# Update single attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento-1, eav, attribute-value

I'm a Magento newbee so please forgive me if there is ... a crap in the code ...
Sending Ajax request with Brand ID and current state "status = 1 or 0" and would like to update state in table:

```
public function BrandsAction()
{
    $brand_id = $this->getRequest()->getPost("brand_id");
    $status = $this->getRequest()->getPost("status");
    $_category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('name', 'Brands')
            ->getFirstItem();

    $categoryId = $_category->getId();
    $brands = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    $brand = $brands->load($brand_id);
    foreach($brand as $element){
        echo $element;
        if($element->getId() == $brand_id){
            $element->getData();
            $element->getAttribute('show_brand');
            $element->setData('show_brand',$status);
            $element->save();
        }
    }
```

I expected **it will update value in column 'show_brand' but it actually does nothing just returning data back** so I can see in  console what values were sent.
How to update value for specified "category -> Brand -> Somebrand" ??
Did I miss something ?

```
//just checking category id
$categoryId = $_category->getId();
//loading selected category
$brands = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
//Loading Brand Data
$brand = $brands->load($brand_id);
```

isn't it ?
Or I misunderstood something ?

Current code:

```
    public function BrandsAction()
    {
    $brandNameId = $this->getRequest()->getPost("brand_id");
    $status = $this->getRequest()->getPost("status");
    $brandsNameCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($brandNameId);
    $brandsNameCat->setShowBrand($status);
    $brandsNameCat->save();
    }
```

not updating values in table ... what I should check to make sure it willl update values ?

Comment: Can you please tell us what these 3 lines of code does `$categoryId = $_category->getId();
    $brands = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    $brand = $brands->load($brand_id);`

Comment: `$brand_id` is this your category id ?

Comment: When you say "Brand ID", is it your category id or id of any other data? or simply do you want to set status of your category called "Brands"?

Comment: Let me clarify a bit. What I wanted to achieve is: in categories I have Brands which contains all the brands so Brands/BrandName. My $brand_id is a BrandName id that's why first I'm getting Parent category ID by name to load it's content then from "parent" picking a BrandName by id ($brand_id). then I want update status for BrandName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case below code should work

```
<?php
function BrandsAction()
{
    $brand_id = $this->getRequest()->getPost("brand_id");
    // I assume $brand_id is your brand name category id which is subcategory or brands (Parent category)
    $status = $this->getRequest()->getPost("status");
    $brandsNameCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($brand_id);
    $brandsNameCat->setShowBrand($status);
    $brandsNameCat->save();
}
```

Comment: Not updating values ;(

Answer (score 3):

To avoid saving the entire model and improve the performance, you can replace the following code:

```
$brandsNameCat->save();
```

With:

```
$brandsNameCat->saveAttribute($brandsNameCat, 'show_brand');
```

Comment: Getting error 503 after this:  replace the code:

$brandsNameCat->save();With:

$brandsNameCat->saveAttribute($brandsNameCat, 'show_brand');

Comment: @RobertA.what's the error message ?

Comment: "POST http://...../brands/ajax/brands/ 503 (Service unavailable)"